# FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all the events from Firestore with this function:

```
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, query, getDocs, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import getCurrentUser from "./CurrentUser";

const getEvents = async () => {
  const uid = getCurrentUser().uid;

  const eventsRef = collection(db, "events", uid);
  const que = query(eventsRef, where("creator", "==", uid));

  const result = await getDocs(que);

  return result;
};

export default getEvents;
```

And I get error: **"FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but events/98HobTnfjndUE1jIBQpKYCeN4hl2 has 2."**

These are the rules of the database:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /events/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I found those rules from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions. If I delete request.auth.uid == userId, it's working but i want to keep it. So how can I make this function work? Thanks.